# what is difference between "firm decision" and "official decision"? in the other word, to understand the difference between FIRM and OFFICIAL

Tags: adjectives, synonyms

what is difference between "firm decision" and "official decision"? in the other word, to understand the difference between FIRM and OFFICIAL.

Recently i learned the difference of following two vocabularies at Oxford Dictionary, so need to figure out what is the difference between them.
  Determine: to *officially* decide or arrange something.
  Resolve: to make a *firm* decision.

Answer (score 1):

A **firm** decision is one that probably won't be changed. "Firm" gives a meaning of finality, certainty and conviction. The person who made the decision intends to stick with (or "stand by") that decision.

An **official** decision is one made by a person or group who carries authority over the matter, and it means the decision has been made and announced using correct established procedures.

A firm decision is not necessarily official, and an official decision is not necessarily firm.